# Inserting Objects into NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

Currently, I have edited a delegate function that adds Exercise objects to an NSMutableArray. However, I would not like to add duplicate objects, instead, if the object is already in the array, i'd like to simply access that particular object.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *str = cell.textLabel.text; // Retrieves the string of the selected cell.

    Exercise *exerciseView = [[Exercise alloc] initWithExerciseName:str];
    WorkoutManager *workoutManager = [WorkoutManager sharedInstance];

    if (![[workoutManager exercises] containsObject:exerciseView]) {
        [[workoutManager exercises] insertObject:exerciseView atIndex:0];
        [self presentModalViewController:exerciseView animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"%@", [workoutManager exercises]); 
    }
    else {
        [self presentModalViewController:exerciseView animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"%@", [workoutManager exercises]); 
    }
}
```

I thought this would work, however, when I ran my code and NSLogged my array, it showed that when I clicked on the same cell, two seperate objects were created. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say this is your culprit:

```
Exercise *exerciseView = [[Exercise alloc] initWithExerciseName:str];
```

You're creating a new object each time so technically, it's not in the array.  The **containsObject** method is just iterating through the array and calling **isEqual** on each object.  I haven't tested this but theoretically, in your custom Exercise object, you could override the **isEqual** method to compare the exercise name properties and return true if they match.  See, EVERYTHING has to match up when you are using **containsObject** so even if all the properties are the same, the objectid is not.

Easy fix without having to see your Exercise implementation:

```
Exercise *exerciseView = nil;

For(Exercise *exercise in [[WorkoutManager sharedInstance] exercises]){
    if(exercise.exerciseName == str) {
        exerciseView = exercise;
        break;
    }
}

if(exerciseView == nil) {
    exerciseView = [[Exercise alloc] initWithExerciseName:str];
    [[workoutManager exercises] insertObject:exerciseView atIndex:0];
}

[self presentModalViewController:exerciseView animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps explain WHY its happening.  I didn't test this code since there are some missing pieces but you should get the idea.  Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

Each time you call

```
Exercise *exerciseView = [[Exercise alloc] initWithExerciseName:str];
```

it create a new (distinct) exerciseView object.  So even though the exercise name may be the same as the name for an exercise object in your exercises list, it is a brand new object so when you call `containsObject` the result will always be false and your new object will be added to the array.

Perhaps you should store a list of the NSString `exerciseName` in your workout manager instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
WorkoutManager *workoutManager = [WorkoutManager sharedInstance];

Exercise *temp = [[Exercise alloc] initWithExerciseName:str];
for(id temp1 in workoutManager)
{
    if( [temp isKindOfClass:[Exercise class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"YES");
        // You Can Access your same object here if array has already same object
    }
}

 [temp release];
 [workoutManager release];
```

Hope, this will help you....